# Jquery ajax in loop bug

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

I don't know , its a bug or not. see my examples :

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'process.php',
    type: "POST",
    data : "abcd",
    success : function(data){
      alert(i);
    }
  })
}
```

or

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  $.post("process.php",{dataw:"abcd"},function(data){
    alert(i);
  })
}
```

why output is 2 ?

Comment: remove the additional 'w' after data in `{dataw:"abcd"}`.

Comment: not related.its only data post name

Comment: it's not an answer just a comment ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` won't keep its value, it'll loop through and stay at the last value (2).

You can wrap your value in a function instead.

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: "abcd",
        success: function(value) {
            return function(data) {
                alert(value);
            }
        }(i)
    })
}
```

Same thing for post:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $.post("process.php", {
            dataw: "abcd"
        },
        function(value) {
            return function(data) {
                alert(value);
            }
        }(i)
    );
}
```

Comment: what about `$.post` ?

Comment: The same thing @AliN11, you make a function that returns a function.